# Workaholic in german

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

How to playfully call someone a **workaholic** in german?

I found many definitions of the equivalent german translation, so I am quite confused which one best suits to this situation. Also, some examples with applications of the translation would help a lot.

Comment: Which translations did you find? Also please tell us, what you want to express, when you call someone a workaholic.

Comment: I want to be playfull and express that the person works too much and should have a break

Comment: (inf) Arbeitswütige(r) mf, Arbeitssüchtige(r) mf, Arbeitstier nt

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Workaholic

Comment: @VictorVerga: please include your clarification into your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German word for *workaholic* is *Workaholic.* We use this English word as a foreign word in German context.

- [7 Anzeichen dafür, dass Sie ein **Workaholic** sind](https://wienerin.at/7-anzeichen-dafur-dass-sie-ein-workaholic-sind)
  <sup>*Wienerin*</sup>
- [Zum Tag der **Workaholics**: Pro und Contra der Arbeitssucht](https://www.karriere.at/blog/workaholic.html)
  <sup>*karriere.at*</sup>
- [Warum es alles andere als sexy ist, ein **Workaholic** zu sein](https://vanilla-mind.de/workaholic/)
  <sup>*Vanilla Mind*</sup>

Other synonyms are used less frequently:

- **Arbeitstier** = working animal
  The main meaning of this word is an animal (horse, elephant, etc.) that is used for work. But there also is this figurative meaning: Person who works too much.
  The word *Arbeitstier* (all meanings together) is used about half as frequent as *Workaholic.*
- **Arbeitsmensch** = working human
  This word is rare (and so are the next ones). *Workaholic* is used about 40 to 50 times more often than *Arbeitsmensch*
- **Arbeitssüchtiger** = person who is addicted to work
  If a psychologist diagnoses that someone works too much, and they wants to use a German name for this condition, then they would use the word *Arbeitssüchtiger.* So, in some sense, this is the "official" German word for *Workaholic,* but it is used about half as often than *Arbeitsmensch,* which means, that *Workaholic* is used about 100 times more often than *Arbeitsmensch.*
- **Workaholiker** = a Germanized version of *Workaholic*
  While *Workaholic* is for 100% a foreign word (English spelling except uppercase W and English pronunciation as far as you can expect English pronunciation from a German native speaker) *Workaholiker* is a loan word and a portmanteau word, blended from the English *work* and the German *Alkoholiker* (= alcoholic, alcohol addict). But from my list, this is the rarest. The foreign word *Workaholic* is used about 100 to 150 times more often than the loan word *Workaholiker*